# Как вывести доп страницы в яндекс? Wordpress

Tags: поисковые-системы, яндекс-поиск

Как вывести в яндекс нечто подобное? Движок Wordpress.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почитать справку "Вебмастер" от Яндекс, нет?

Comment: @IgorR. R Поделитесь пожалуйста ссылкой, где именно там об этом рассказывается

Comment: Например, [вот здесь](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/recommendations/search-results-presentation.html).